# How to make rfacebook code work from command line?

Tags: r, facebook-graph-api, command-line

I want to use R for loading facebook posts and analyze them, all of this I want to do on server machine, so when I run following code in terminal:

```
library("Rfacebook")
library("httr")
fb_oauth <- fbOAuth(app_id="appid", app_secret="secret")
save(fb_oauth,file = "fb_oauth")
load("fb_oauth")
fb_page <- getPage(page="facebook", token=fb_oauth)
## Getting posts on Humans of New York page, including posts by others users
## (not only owner of page)
token = "mythoken"
page <- getPage(page="humansofnewyork", token=token, feed=TRUE)
```

I got following error:
    Copy and paste into Site URL on Facebook App Settings:

```
http://localhost:1410/ 
When done, press any key to continue...
Error: oauth_listener() needs an interactive environment.
Execution halted
```

But in Rstudio, it works. How I can make it work on server?

Comment: the code of the function is [here](https://github.com/pablobarbera/Rfacebook/blob/master/Rfacebook/R/fbOAuth.R), make a `fbOAuth2` function where you remove the `invisible(readLine(message))`. You probably can't get away not using the browser authentification afterwards though